# Seq empty test with specs2

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs, specs2

How can I check if a `Seq[String]` is empty or not using specs2 in Scala ? I am using `seq must be empty` or `seq.length must be greaterThan(0)` but I end up always with type mismatch errors.

```
ret is Seq[String]

ret.length must be greaterThan(0)

[error] ApiTest.scala:99: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int
[error]  required: org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[String]
[error]         ret.length must be greaterThan(0)
```

Comment: You might be more lucky if you posted the exact code and the corresponding error message as given by the compiler.

Comment: Yes please add a more complete example. I think that your case might be an instance of a "classical" type inference issue where you have consecutive matcher expressions separated by newlines, like "ret.length must be greaterThan(0) \n ret.lenght must beLowerThan(10)" (if that's the case I'll edit this comment as a proper answer)

Answer (score 3):

I think the type mismatch error is caused by another bit of code than that which you've posted.

Your example should just work with:

```
ret must not be empty
```

I've tried and confirmed to be working correctly:

```
 "Seq beEmpty test" should {
    "just work" in {
      Seq("foo") must not be empty
    }
  }
```

You could run into trouble if you use multiple assertions per test, for example the following doesn't compile:

```
"Seq beEmpty test" should {
  "just work" in {
    List() must be empty
    Seq("foo") must not be empty
  }
}
```

Which is unexpected, but easily fixed by helping the compiler:

```
"Seq beEmpty test" should {
  "just work" in {
    List() must beEmpty
    Seq("foo") must not beEmpty
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `beEmpty` by default?

Comment: @OrangeDog only the elegance of 'be empty' over 'beEmpty' can be an argument. They are semantically the same.

Comment: Neither of the options works for mutable.Specification for Specs2 v 4.10.6

Comment: @AlbertBikeev you're welcome to edit the answer. It's 8y old now, so maybe the whole question has lost relevance?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the specs2 matcher `have size`. Since the size can't be negative, if it's not zero, it must be greater than zero. Therefore, we could use:

```
ret must not have size (0)
```