# specs2: Multiple matcher expressions (Unit specification)

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs2

How can I check multiple expressions in one Matcher fragment?

For example:

```
class Foo extends Specification {
   "Retrieving open issues" should {
      "return expected properties with expected data" in     {
         val issue = Bar.openIssues.head

         issue must not beNull
         issue.number must beEqualTo(1) 
         issue.state must beEqualTo("open")
         issue.title must beEqualTo("first issue")
      }
   }
}
```

Gives error

```
[error]  type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int
[error]  required: org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[Issue]
[error]                         issue.number must beEqualTo(1)
```

Eric references a "classical" type inference issue in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511310/seq-empty-test-with-specs2#comment16857709_12511310), but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: try to add parentheses to this line: `(issue must not beNull)`. Does this solve the issue?

Comment: Yes. If you make this an answer (and explain why this helps, if you please) I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
issue must not beNull
```

Because it is written in operator notation the compiler must infer dots and parentheses at the right position. Following the rule that `obj meth arg` is the same as `obj.meth(arg)` this line is interpreted as:

```
issue.must(not).beNull<missing_arg>
```

`beNull` is a member called on the returned value of `issue.must(not)`. The compiler follows the rules of operator notation and treats it as `meth` while `issue.must(not)` is treated as `obj`. Because operator notation always requires that a call must have the form `obj meth arg`, in the above example the compiler is hold to throw an error because of invalid syntax. But it doesn't do it since there are two further rules:

1. The white space that separates the identifiers in operator notation must not only contain spaces or tabs, it can also contain a single(!) new line sign.
2. If no `arg` can be found an empty argument list is inserted implicitly.

Because of (1), the compiler treats the next line as `arg`:

```
issue.must(not).beNull(
issue.number).must(beEqualTo(1))
```

This is not how the code should be interpreted. To solve the problem it is possible to enclose the whole expression in parentheses:

```
(issue must not beNull)
```

or to separate the lines by an empty line:

```
issue must not beNull

issue.number must beEqualTo(1)
```

Both solutions work because of (2) the compiler can insert an empty argument list.

Note: If (2) must be applied this is also called a postfix operator. In 2.10 they treat a warning because - as one can see with this question - they can lead to tricky behavior.

Comment: Other fixes are: `issue must not(beNull)` or `issue must not beNull;`